# Cannot start Hyper-V container

Tags: docker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyfWk.png)I am trying to run the docker container but I am getting below error message as Hyper-V and Virtualization is not enabled. But I have enabled Hyper-V and virtualization. I have made the Hyper-V set-up through Bios as well as through the power shell command even though getting this below error. Kindly help me!

Error message :

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error
>   response from daemon: failed to start service utility VM
>   (createreadwrite): CreateComputeSystem
>   190e30a0debfc2e6f9eeedd4b1732593f80b2b478210faa5f92f8bc69c3a5686_svm:
>   No hypervisor is present on this system.
>
> [Event Detail: Cannot start
>   Hyper-V Container
>   '190e30a0debfc2e6f9eeedd4b1732593f80b2b478210faa5f92f8bc69c3a5686_svm'
>   since the hypervisor is not running in the host. Provider:
>   17103e3f-3c6e-4677-bb17-3b267eb5be57 EventID: 12001]
>
> (extra info: {"SystemType":"container","Name":"190e30a0debfc2e6f9eeedd4b1732593f80b2b478210faa5f92f8bc69c3a5686_svm","Layers":null,"HvPartition":true,"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\Program
>   Files\LinuxContainers","LinuxInitrdFile":"initrd.img","LinuxKernelFile":"kernel"},"ContainerType":"linux","TerminateOnLastHandleClosed":true}).
>
> See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run
>   --help'.

Comment: can you confirm if my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I needed also an extra step which enabling the virtualization from the bios.

- Open the bios
- going to security => virtualization
- Enable the two options (see image 01)
- Restart

Make sure that the virtualization is enabled by running the task manager => Performance => down you should see virtualization enabled (see image 02).

[image: Enable the virtualization from the bios]
[image: Make sure that the virtualization is enabled from the task manager]

> Ps: Check also if the hyper-V and container are enabled from control panel => Programs and features => Turn Windows Features on or off

[image: Enable the Hyper-V and Container From control panel]

> Make sure to enable all those features pointed by the arrow in the image

[image: All things you need enable for docker]

> Also make sure to switch to Linux container by seeing this in the docker shortcut in the task manager bar (if you see this result image it means is switched on :)). This to prevent futures problems like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60967930/unable-to-build-a-docker-image-on-windows-10).

[image: Switch to Linux container]

And then restart your system and restart the docker too.
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested from the support in a chat I tried to start Hyper-V from the Hyper-V-Manager and this failed. I found a solution for this following this post: https://superuser.com/a/1160635/777303

Basically running `bcdedit` from the cmd in admin mode showed me that `hypervisorlaunchtype` was set to `off`.

Running `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` and rebooting solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
https://www.jennerstrand.se/an-error-occurred-cannot-enable-hyper-v-service/

Basicly:

- Disable Hyper-V
- Enable Hyper-V

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Go to `turn windows features on or off` (if you write `optionalfeatures` in cmd you got that files)
- There search for a file with the name `windows hypervisor platform`
- Enable it.
- Reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion sir, i have tried for the steps what you said although i am getting the same error message. please find the attached screenshot,

Comment: Then check if you have enable virtualization (task manager => performance). Check in service of Hyper-V is running, and restart docker. This is all I can apport you and how I solve it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to

> Turn Windows features on or off

- Enable

> Containers

- Reboot