# Unable to build a Docker image on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, docker

Windows 10 Pro 1909
Docker 2.2.0.4 (43472)

Dockerfile starts like this:

```
FROM debian:stable-20191118
```

And that is the only part that works (or any other linux like `ubuntu:18.04`)
Any next line, like any of these

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y nginx
```

gets the same error:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c (insert any of the commands above)' returned a non-zero code: 4294967295:
failed to shutdown container: container ad12191abf0849d5e49bb5dc0570d6ba8eaf2cc5b4e7d77127ed381901fcb672 
encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure in a Windows system call: 
The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110): 
subsequent terminate failed container ad12191abf0849d5e49bb5dc0570d6ba8eaf2cc5b4e7d77127ed381901fcb672 
encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure in a Windows system call: 
The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110)
```

Command is

```
docker build -f Dockerfile . --no-cache
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? Struggling with as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem. But when I switched to Linux containers it helped.
If you use Linux containers than you will see "Switch to Windows containers..." when you press RMB on Docker.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Looks like idea to get it working under "mixed" mode, where it's possible to run both Windows and Linux containers.

Comment: I get error while trying to switch to linux container. What could be the issue?

Comment: Linux building container, returns the same error under Win10