# how to start a Redis server on port 6379

Tags: django, docker, websocket, redis, django-channels

i'm getting this error while working with django channels tutorial project

> ```
> redis:5
>
> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to start service utility VM
> (createreadwrite): hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem
> 9eb1deb8fc69ee2656d9e049530b329c0fa8ca44a1f6523e9d5a27768fbedb62_svm:
> The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is
> not installed. (extra info:
> {"SystemType":"container","Name":"9eb1deb8fc69ee2656d9e049530b329c0fa8ca44a1f6523e9d5a27768fbedb62_svm","Layers":null,"HvPartition":true,"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\Program
> Files\\Linux
> Containers","LinuxInitrdFile":"initrd.img","LinuxKernelFile":"kernel"},"ContainerType":"linux","TerminateOnLastHandleClosed":true}).
> ```

Comment: That might be an error with how Docker itself is installed or setup on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have not enabled hyper-V and container.Please check if the hyper-V and container are enabled from control panel => Programs and features => Turn Windows Features on or off

[image: see this]

If you have still issue then plese check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56404713/cannot-start-hyper-v-container).

Comment: Hyper-V is not showing up!